# Deleted a specific commit on Github due to a KEY exposure

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I forgot to delete a comment line in my commit and wonder how to delete a specific I don't want to use `git revert` because I already pushed other commits. I do the `git-filter-repo` method but it throw me an error of on `git push origin --force --all`.
I just want to delete the commit to cleanup the history of Github...

I already do this once but don't remember how. I checked the Git doc but doesn't find the way to do it and I don't understand why Gitguardian doesn't allow us to remove these. I am the only one on this project an no one has forked/cloned the project. This is also a public folder.

Any advice ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+commit

Comment: Esp. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758

Comment: "it throw me an error", care to tell us what the error message was? If you filtered away the commit locally, and did a force-push, that should've worked.

Comment: @phd all of this doesn't work. @Lasse V.Karlsen For the "Bfg repo-cleaner" on `java -jar bfg.jar  --replace-text private.txt  my-repo.git`I got "Unable to access jarfile bfg.jar" despite I downloaded it ; `git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
  "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch PATH-TO-YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all` Wich PATH ? the relative PATH from my local or the PATH from github? `  git push --force --verbose --dry-run` got "No configured push destination."